# This "is not a function" (Pine-Script)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I've copied exactly this simple code (Pine Script) from a Youtuber's video, but somehow it doesn't work for me.
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3Sq6snvFQs

CODE [Summarized]:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Hammers and Shooting Stars", shorttitle="Pin Bars")
plot(close)

// Get user input
fibLevel = input(title="Fib Level", type=input.float, defval=0.333)
colorFilter = input(title="Color Must Match", type=input.bool, defval=false)

// Calculate fibonacci level for current candle
bullFib = (low - high) * fibLevel + high
bearFib = (high - low) * fibLevel + low

// Determine which price source closes or opens highest/lowest
lowestBody = close < open ? close : open
highestBody = close > open ? close : open

// Determine if we have a valid hammer or shooting star
hammerCandle = lowestBody >= bullFib (not colorFilter or close > open)
starCandle = highestBody <= bearFib (not colorFilter or close < open)
```

PROBLEM:

'bullFib'is not a function (in this line):

```
hammerCandle = lowestBody >= bullFib (not colorFilter or close > open)
```

'bearFib' is not a function (in this line):

```
starCandle = highestBody <= bearFib (not colorFilter or close < open)
```

What are being referred to:

```
bullFib = (low - high) * fibLevel + high
bearFib = (high - low) * fibLevel + low
```

I'm not a coder, I'm learning to code just now, but this problem is happenning a lot. But it's strange when it happens when this is a copied code that works in someone else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just incorrect syntax error. You forgot `and` logical operator between `bullFib` and `(not colorFilter or close > open))`

Take this line

```
hammerCandle = lowestBody >= bullFib (not colorFilter or close > open)
```

where `bullFib` and `lowestBody` is some float variables (numbers).

Here is comparison operation

```
lowestBody >= bullFib
```

Which results in `true` or `false`.

next

```
(not colorFilter or close > open)
```

this is logical operators too, which results in `true` or `false`.
Simplify this and you will get:

`hammerCandle = condition1 (condition2)` which is incorrect. Just add logical operator between and then this would make sense.

`hammerCandle = condition1 and condition2`

---

So correct syntax will be

```
hammerCandle = lowestBody >= bullFib and (not colorFilter or close > open)
```